# pathogen is not executed when I am starting vim on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, vim, pathogen

I am new to VIM. I tried to install [pathogen.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) plugin. I will describe the folder structure.

```
--- /etc/vim
            -vimrc
            -vimrc.tiny
            -autoload
              -pathogen.vim
            -bundle
```

I have not added anything in the bundle yet.

In the vimrc file I have added few lines

```
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

But it was throwing the error whenever I was starting vim from my terminal.

ERROR -

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vimrc:
line   57:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I then tried adding

```
runtime /etc/vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

on top of the calling the pathogen infect function, but nothing is happening. And in the error the path shown is `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`, may be because `etc/vim/vimrc is the symlink`. I am not sure, I am new to it.

Comment: Why not place configuration files in your home directory (`~/.vim`)? Also I'd guess that you should place those pathogen config lines at the beginning of your `.vimrc`

Comment: Which configuration files?
pathogen.vim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No. Don't touch system files, ever.**

Whatever you have done in `/etc` *must* be done in `/home/username`:

```
/home/username/.vim   <-- the directory where you put your plugins
                          and colorschemes and stuff

/home/username/.vimrc <-- the file where you put your settings
```

The pathogen plugin should be there:

```
/home/username/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

The bundle directory should be there:

```
/home/username/.vim/bundle
```

The three lines should be in this file:

```
/home/username/.vimrc
```

Comment: I am sorry but there is no .vim folder in my home directory (home/username/), that is why i changed the system files

Comment: Do I have to create the .vim and .vimrc folder and file in the home dir explicitly?

Comment: I have created .vim dir and .vimrc file in home/username dir, and guess what - it worked like charm.

Thanks for the guidance. :)

Can we conclude that whatever system files are tere we can manipulate them by adding a .file to the home dir and making changes to them?

Comment: No. You should completely forget abbout those system files. Whatever you do to configure Vim must *always* be done in `$HOME`, whatever you have in `/etc` is irrelevant to your configuration effort.